# Getting text part of select instead of value in jqGrid inline editing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

In my jqGrid there are 4 select in which two is working fine and two is not working.

Issue :
When I use the below snippet :

```js
 var stagevalues = GetStagesValues();
  var salesvalues = GetSalesValues();
  var owners = GetDataOwnershipValues();
  xmlstring = Stages; //.XmlToString();
  $("#uxStages").jqGrid({
   datatype: 'xmlstring',
   datastr: xmlstring,
   mtype: 'GET',
   ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
   xmlReader: { repeatitems: false, root: "BO>SalesOpportunitiesLines", row: 'row' },
   colNames: ['LineNum', 'Star Date', 'Close Date', 'Sales Employee', 'Stage', 'Percentage', 'Potential Amount', 'Document Type', 'Doc. No.', 'Owner'],
   colModel: [
    { name: 'LineNum', key: true, index: 'LineNum', hidden: false, sortable: false, width: 60 },
    { name: 'StartDate', key: false, index: 'StartDate', sortable: false, align: "left", width: 90,
     editable: true,
     formatter: 'date',
     formatoptions: { srcformat: 'Ymd', newformat: 'd-M-y' },
     formatter: function (cellValue, opts, rawdata, action) {
      if (action === "edit") {
       // input data have format "dd-mm-yy" format - "20-03-2015"
       var input = cellValue.split("-");
       if (input.length === 3) {
        return input[0] + "-" + input[1] + "-" + input[2];
       }
      } else if (cellValue.length === 8) {
       // input data have format "yymmdd" format - "20150320"
       var year = cellValue.substr(0, 4), month = cellValue.substr(4, 2), day = cellValue.substr(6, 2);
       return day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
      }
      return cellValue; // for empty input for example
     },
     editoptions: {
      dataInit: function (elem) {
       $(elem).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-y' });
      }
     }
    },
    { name: 'ClosingDate', key: false, index: 'ClosingDate', sortable: false, align: "left", width: 90,
     editable: true,
     formatter: 'date',
     formatoptions: { srcformat: 'Ymd', newformat: 'd-m-Y' },
     formatter: function (cellValue, opts, rawdata, action) {
      if (action === "edit") {
       // input data have format "dd-mm-yy" format - "20-03-2015"
       var input = cellValue.split("-");
       if (input.length === 3) {
        return input[0] + "-" + input[1] + "-" + input[2];
       }
      } else if (cellValue.length === 8) {
       // input data have format "yymmdd" format - "20150320"
       var year = cellValue.substr(0, 4), month = cellValue.substr(4, 2), day = cellValue.substr(6, 2);
       return day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
      }
      return cellValue; // for empty input for example
     },
     editoptions: {
      dataInit: function (elem) {
       $(elem).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' });
      }
     }
    },
    { name: 'SalesPerson', key: false, index: 'SalesPerson', sortable: false, width: 80,
     editable: true,
     edittype: "select"
    },
    { name: 'StageKey', key: false, index: 'StageKey', hidden: false, sortable: false, width: 80,
     editable: true,
     edittype: "select"
    },
    { name: 'PercentageRate', key: false, index: 'PercentageRate', sortable: false, width: 60 },
    { name: 'MaxLocalTotal', key: false, index: 'MaxLocalTotal', sortable: false, width: 100,
     editable: true,
     edittype: "text",
     formatter: 'currency',
     formatoptions: { thousandsSeparator: ',' }
    },
    { name: 'DocumentType', key: false, index: 'DocumentType', sortable: false, width: 90,
     editable: true,
     edittype: 'select',
     formatter: 'select',
     editoptions: {value: "bodt_MinusOne:;bodt_Quotation:Sales Quotations;bodt_Order:Sales Orders;bodt_DeliveryNote:Deliveries;bodt_Invoice:A/R Invoice"
     }
    },
    { name: 'DocumentNumber', key: false, index: 'DocumentNumber', sortable: false, width: 40 },
    { name: 'DataOwnershipfield', key: false, index: 'DataOwnershipfield', hidden: false, sortable: false, width: 60,
     editable: true,
     edittype: "select",
     unformat: function (cellValue, opts, rawdata, action) {
      $('#uxOwner').each(function () {
       $('option', this).each(function () {
        //        if (opts.rowId == 4)
        //         debugger;
        var code = $(this).val();
        var name = $(this).text();
        if (name == cellValue)
         return code;
       });
      });
     }
    }
   ],
   rowNum: 100,
   viewrecords: true,
   gridview: true,
   rownumbers: true,
   height: 150,
   loadonce: true,
   width: 1120,
   scrollOffset: 0,
   ondblClickRow: function (rowid) {
    var grid = $("#uxStages");
    var selectedRowId = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    lastSelection = selectedRowId;
    grid.jqGrid('editRow', selectedRowId, true, null, null, null, null, OnSuccessEdit_Stages);
    $('#' + selectedRowId + "_StageKey").css('width', '100%');
    $('#' + selectedRowId + "_SalesPerson").css('width', '100%');
    $('#' + selectedRowId + "_DataOwnershipfield").css('width', '100%');
    $('#' + selectedRowId + "_DocumentType").css('width', '100%');
   },
   loadComplete: function () {
    var ids = $("#uxStages").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
     var id = ids[i];
     if (i < ids.length) {
      $("#uxStages").jqGrid('editRow', id);
      $("#uxStages").setColProp('SalesPerson', { edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: salesvalues} }); //Here i m fetching values in namedvalue pairs
      $("#uxStages").setColProp('StageKey', { edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: stagevalues} }); //Here i m fetching values in namedvalue pairs
      $("#uxStages").setColProp('DataOwnershipfield', { edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: owners} }); //Here i m fetching values in namedvalue pairs
      $("#uxStages").saveRow(id);
     }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
     var id = ids[i];
     if (i < ids.length - 1) {
      //      $('#' + $.jgrid.jqID(id)).addClass('not-editable-row');
      //      $('#' + $.jgrid.jqID(id)).addClass('ui-state-error');
     }
    }
   },
   onSelectRow: function (id) {
    if (id && id !== lastSelection) {
     var grid = $("#uxStages");
     $('#uxStages').saveRow(lastSelection);
    }
   }
  }).jqGrid('navGrid', { edit: true, edit: true, add: true, del: true, searchOnEnter: false, search: false }, {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: false }).trigger('reloadGrid');




function OnSuccessEdit_Stages(id, response, options) {

 var LineNum = $('#uxStages').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'LineNum');
 var StartDate = $('#uxStages').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'StartDate');
 var ClosingDate = $('#uxStages').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'ClosingDate');
 var SalesPerson = $('#uxStages').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'SalesPerson'); //getting text part of select and expected to get value
 var StageKey = $('#uxStages').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'StageKey'); //getting text part of select and expected to get value
 var PercentageRate = $('#uxStages').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'PercentageRate');
 var MaxLocalTotal = $('#uxStages').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'MaxLocalTotal');
 var DocumentType = $('#uxStages').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'DocumentType'); //getting value which is correct
 var DocumentNumber = $('#uxStages').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'DocumentNumber');
 var DataOwnershipfield = $('#uxStages').jqGrid('getCell', id, 'DataOwnershipfield'); //getting value which is correct

 $oppor.find('Response Data BOM BO SalesOpportunitiesLines row').each(function (index) {
  if ($(this).find('LineNum').text() == LineNum) {
   if (LineNum == 4)
   //   $(this).find('StartDate').text(StartDate);
   //   $(this).find('ClosingDate').text(ClosingDate);
    $(this).find('SalesPerson').text(SalesPerson);
   $(this).find('StageKey').text(StageKey);
   $(this).find('PercentageRate').text(PercentageRate);
   $(this).find('MaxLocalTotal').text(MaxLocalTotal);
   $(this).find('DocumentType').text(DocumentType);
   $(this).find('DocumentNumber').text(DocumentNumber);
   $(this).find('DataOwnershipfield').text(DataOwnershipfield);

  }
 });
 return true;
}
```

I am getting text part in first 2 select instead of value where as in the last 2 select it gives me value instead of text which is expected.

I use unformat function also to get the value part, But doesn't work.

I want somebody to point me the issue, I don't know how to deal with such issues.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: Sorry, but why you makes so difficult for other to read your code? You write about the "first 2 select" for example. The reader have to scroll through your code skip many first columns to find the selects. Do you mean that you have problems with `SalesPerson` and `StageKey` columns? Why you don't write that? Even the formatting of the code is terrible. Why you don't remove unneeded space on the left size of the code before posting the code. Why you absolutely don't think about the reader of your question?

Comment: If `SalesPerson` and `StageKey` columns are really the columns where you have the problems then you **have to post the value** which you set (`salesvalues` and `stagevalues`). It's clear that if the values are wrong then you will have wrong results. Moreover you call **$("#uxStages").jqGrid('editRow', id); for multiple rows inside of `loadComplete`**.  It seems very suspected. Moreover you change values of `SalesPerson` **in the loop** and even **before you start editing of the row**. It's VERY suspected too.

Comment: Oh Ic... let me make work on suspicious area... If required I will edit my post... Problem in two column "SalesPerson" & "StageKey", I am pulling values (salesvalues/stagevalues) in the form as specified Ex: "1:A;2:B;3:C"

Comment: Sorry, but you should be very exact. If you have the same problem in two columns "SalesPerson" & "StageKey", let's speak just about one column `SalesPerson` for example. If you want to locale an error it's not enough that you write `Ex: "1:A;2:B;3:C"`. It's very important **what exact values you set** I wrote you before that you call `editRow` **in the loop** and you **change `editoptions.value` in the loop too**. Do you really need to have **different** selects in different rows? Moreover you set `editoptions.value` **after** call of `editRow`. So the call in the first row don't have `value`.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks, issue is resolved and you point pain area very correctly, it is in the loadComplete event. Once again thanks for your support.

Comment: @You are welcome! I'm glad that the problem is solved finally.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of the problem could be the wrong order of calls `editRow` and `setColProp` in the for-loop inside of `loadComplete`. If you need to change `editoptions.value`, which will be used during editing, you should use it **before** the editing will be started. Thus `setColProp` should be called before `editRow`.

The call of `saveRow` directly after call of `editRow` seems me very suspected. You set `salesvalues`, `stagevalues` and `owners` **before** you crated the grid (see the lines `var salesvalues = GetSalesValues();` and other). So it seems that you can use

```
{ name: 'SalesPerson', width: 80, editable: true, edittype: "select", 
    editoptions: { value: salesvalues} }
```

directly in `colModel`. No loop inside of `loadComplete` seems be required.